# Solr performance with multiple fields

Tags: performance, solr, field

I have to index around 10 million documents in solr for full text search. Each of these documents have around 25 additional metadata fields attached to them. Each of the metadata fields individually are small (upto 64 characters). Common queries would be involving a search term along with multiple metadata fields used to filter the data. So my questions is which would provide better performance wrt search response time. (indexing time is not a concern):

a. Index the text data as well as push all metadata fields into solr as stored fields  and query solr for all the fields using a single query. (Effectively solr does the filtering with metadata as well as search)

b. Store the metadata fields in a db like Mysql. Use solr only for full text and then use the document ids returned from solr as an input to the database to filter based on other metadata to retrieve the final set of documents.

Thanks 
Arijit

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a). Solr isn't simply a fulltext search engine, it's much more. It's filter queries are at least as good/fast as MySQL select.

b) is just silly. Fetch many ids from MySQL by selecting those with correct metadata, do a fulltext search in Solr while filtering against that ids list, fetch document from MySQL or Solr (if you choose to store data in it, not just indexes). I can't imagine a case where this would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things, especially if indexing time and HD space is not an issue, you should store all your data (meaning: subset needed by users) in Solr.

Exception would be if you had large amount of text to store (and retrieve) in each document. In those cases it would be faster to fetch it from RDB after you get your search results back. Anyway, noone can tell for sure which one would be faster in your case, so I suggest you test performance of both approaches (using JMeter for example).

Also, since you don't care about index time, you should do all the processing you can at index time instead of at query time (e.g. synonyms, payloads where they can replace boosting, ...).

See here for some additional info on Solr performance:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors